# Is it possible to resize a ce-image with max values and fill the gaps with a background color?

Tags: ce-image

I am trying to resize images (logos) to a max of 150px width and 150px height. Since these images differ greatly in original width and height I would like to center the generated image and then fill the gaps with a background color.

What I would like to end up with is a 150px x 150px image every time with logo centered... is this possible with CE Image?

Here is my current tag.

```
{exp:ce_img:pair src="{logo}" max_height="150" max_width="150" crop="no"}
    <img class="media-object" src="{made}" height="{height}" width="{width}" alt="{title}" />
{/exp:ce_img:pair}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's an example on the CE Image docs ([common solutions](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/common-solutions), option 2 - watermark) - essentially you need a blank image file that you can stretch as a watermark behind the resized graphic. Something like this (derived from the example on that page):

```
{exp:ce_img:pair src="{logo}" parse="inward" max="150" crop="yes"}
    {exp:ce_img:single src="/images/white_spec.png"
watermark="{made}|0,0|100|center,center" width="150" height="150" crop="yes" allow_scale_larger="yes"}
{/exp:ce_img:pair}
```